# How does JavaScript runtime relate to C#?

Tags: c#, .net

While going through the [*Understand the .NET debugger in Visual Studio Code*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/dotnet-debug/3-analyze-your-program-state) section of [one of the learning modules from MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/dotnet-debug/), I came across the following statement:

> **Global variables** are accessible from everywhere in your program. System objects from the JavaScript runtime are also included, so don't be surprised if you see a lot of stuff in there.

Where does the JavaScript runtime come into picture while compiling and executing C# code?

There has been no mention of the JSRE in any of the previous learning modules, rather it talked about the .NET runtime environment and the .NET compiler.

Comment: "Where does the JavaScript runtime come into picture while compiling and executing C# code?" It probably doesn't unless you're debugging JavaScript code.

Comment: I think it's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where does the JavaScript runtime come into picture while compiling and executing C# code?

It doesn't. --- Well exceptions are everywhere [Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [WebAssemblies](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/net-and-webassembly-is-this-the-future-of-the-frontend), [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr).

The article is about the debugger - which is apparently capable of fetching data from multiple sources for convenience.

---

I must say I haven't debugged JavaScript with that particular debugger - I mainly stick to Visual Studio. I am curious to see what it can do. If it doesn't work: it must be a typo.

Comment: So I'm guessing the article talks about the case when we are using .NET for the web?

Comment: More importantly: it talks about the debuggers possibility to look into the JavaScript runtime memory so you can easily debug. Typically compiled .net code is not depending on JavaScript with some exceptions here and there.